# Unable to change where Git is loaded in Mac

Tags: git, macos, path, startup

I have MacPorts' Git at /opt/local/bin/git, while the newest Git at /opt/local/git.

**My PATH command**

```
export PATH=/usr/local/git:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/Masi/.cabal/bin:/Users/Masi/.cabal/bin/xmonad:$PATH
```

The command

```
echo $PATH
```

gives me

```
/usr/local/git:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:Users/Masi/.cabal/bin:/Users/Sam/.cabal/bin/xmonad:/sw/bin:/sw/sbin:$PATH:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin/perl::/usr/X11R6/bin
```

I run the following command and get MacPorts' Git

```
which git
/opt/local/bin/git
```

Aaron says

> Add /opt/local/git as the first
>   element in the path, then
>   /opt/local/bin/. This way, your git
>   will be found, first, and everything
>   else from `/opt/local/bin/ will be
>   available, too.

I did not get the newest Git to be run although I have it first in my PATH.

**How can you change Git to be loaded from the second PATH?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two solutions:

1. Add `/opt/local/git` as the first element in the path, then `/opt/local/bin/`. This way, your git will be found, first, and everything else from ``/opt/local/bin/` will be available, too.
2. Create a new `bin/` directory somewhere, create soft links (`ln -s`) for all programs which you need in there and then but that `bin/` as the first thing into your path.

Comment: The problem solved. I had a wrong folder in my PATH. It should be /usr/local/git/bin. --- Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't put binaries in `/opt/local`.  Unless there's a particular reason you need an older version of git, you shouldn't have two copies installed.  Leave the `/opt` hierarchy for macports.  If you want to build a software package on your own, install it into `/usr/local`.  This would put the `git` binary in `/usr/local/bin`.  Whichever of `/usr/local/bin` and `/opt/local/bin` is first in $PATH, files in that directory will take precedence.