# Unable to push code to git remote

Tags: git

I am trying to add remote using git remote add and than am trying to push to that remote but am getting following errors:

`fatal: 'adoshi_01': unable to chdir or not a git archive`
and
`fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

Steps followed:

- First of all I cloned from `git/repos/scripts` to `home/adoshi/repos/scripts` using command `git clone git01.dev:home/git/repos/scripts.git`,
- after doing this I looked at `home/git/devs/adoshi` folder and there were not entries for scripts and I am still wondering why.
- Then I tried to add files using `git add .`
- Then  committed them using `git commit –am “Detailed Message”`
- Added remote using `git remote add adoshi_01 git01.dev:/home/git/devs/adoshi/scripts/` - Thing to notice there is not scripts folder in `git01.dev`
- Tried to push using `git push adoshi_git01 master` – But again it gave me error

I think main issue here =
On `git01.dev:/home/git/devs/adoshi/`,   “`scripts`” folder was not created even after I cloned it in 1st and so am still wondering as to what might be the possible reason for that.

Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you troubleshoot the issue as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922210/unable-to-git-push-master-to-github ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `git-push` will not create a repository on the other end. Assuming you have shell access to `git01.dev`, first create a bare repository to hold your public repository:

```
ssh git01.dev git init --bare /home/git/devs/adoshi/scripts.git
```

Now clone the shared repo:

```
git clone git01.dev:/home/git/repos/scripts.git
```

Now move into your cloned repo and push it to your new bare repository:

```
cd scripts
git remote add adoshi_01 git01.dev:/home/git/devs/adoshi/scripts.git
git push --all adoshi_01
```

Comment: I have followed the same steps mentioned in questions and am getting exact response out as fatal errors also mentioned in email.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have write permissions on the appropriate directories on the server?