# Why does "git push origin master" fail to github?

Tags: git

Here are the steps I took.

1. I created a repository on github
   and
2. generated a rails project on my
   windows vista home premium (which
   has msys git 1.7.0.2).
3. git init
4. I then committed the generated files
5. git remote add origin
   git@github.com:anjanb/Jobs2Go.git
6. git push origin master

On the 5th step, I get the following error.
*"Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly*"

I vaguely remember following some sshgen steps I took when I created my 1st github repository but I have forgotten what it was.

Can someone point me what I did wrong, what I need to do right.

Thank you,

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922210/unable-to-git-push-master-to-github help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to [add your public SSH-key to github](http://help.github.com/linux-key-setup/).

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://github.com/guides/providing-your-ssh-key) is the help page on SSH keys