# git push origin master failed

Tags: git, github

I want to push my code to github.com.

I use win Xp and git-bash 1.7.2.3

And I got following success message during ssh testing.

But "`git push origin master`" command require username and password.

```
debug1: Entering interactive session.  
ERROR: Hi xxx! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provi
de shell access  
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0  
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1  
Connection to github.com closed.  
debug1: Transferred: stdin 0, stdout 0, stderr 34 bytes in 0.7 seconds  
debug1: Bytes per second: stdin 0.0, stdout 0.0, stderr 51.8  
debug1: Exit status 1

rafael@NETBOOK-RAFAEL /d/project/clojure/anagram (master)

$ git push origin master

Username:

`fatal: Could not read password: No such file or directory`
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a ssh key and upload the public key to github, so that it will be able to authenticate you using the key. I think that in Windows, the ssh key resides inside the .ssh folder of your profile (`c:\documents and settings\<username>`). So, create the key and upload the contents of id_rsa.pub (this is the name unless you change it) to Github.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your GitHub id? (since GitHub is based on [Token identification](http://github.com/blog/170-token-authentication))

```
git config --global github.user "your-github-username"
git config --global github.token "your-github-token"
```

See [GitHub Help page](http://help.github.com/git-email-settings/).

---

Regarding [Vasileios Lourdas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440932/vasileios-lourdas)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745664/git-push-origin-master-failed/3745725#3745725) about ssh, make sure what is the value of `$HOME` in a git bash session.

```
VonC@VONC ~
$ pwd
/c/Users/VonC

Vonc@VONC ~
$ echo $HOME
/c/Users/VonC
```

On Xp, that would be `c:\Document And Settings\VonC`.
Meaning your ssh public key file id_rsa.pub must have the path:

```
 c:\Document And Settings\VonC\.ssh\id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: @VonC: sorry for late response. rafael@NETBOOK-RAFAEL ~/.ssh
$ echo $HOME
/c/Documents and Settings/rafael

Comment: @rafael: so you do have an id_rsa.pub file in `/c/Documents and Settings/rafael/.ssh` directory?

Comment: @rafael: and you did copy that public key in your GitHub account?

Comment: @rafael: from a git bash session, what a `ssh -v` returns? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922210/unable-to-git-push-master-to-github/922461#922461)

Answer (score 0):

It may be a problem with using HTTPS interface.  Change to the directory and run "git remote -v" to list how your remotes are configured, then post it.