# Git shows the error "does not appear to be a git repository fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly"

Tags: git

I just installed GIT in my CentOS Linux server and configured it. When I create a new repository using `git init` it works fine and gives output of the command also.
But whenever I try to clone the remote repository into my local computer folder it gives the following message:

```
fatal: '/public_html/repositories/git-test/.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Has anyone come across this issue, what could be the reason?

Comment: can you give the full clone command that you're using to help further debug.

Comment: You said "local" - does that mean you're cloning over a network? Does your login on the remote have the necessary privileges to read all of the files? (And I second Nigel's request for full information.)

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/922566/327862

Answer (score 11):

Your path may be incomplete. Perhaps your full path should be something more like this: `/home/USER/public_html/repositories/git-test`.

Comment: Thanks Kanaka for the answer, actually iam using both mysys GIT and Tortoise GIT for this purpose.

Now i used the format "git@myhost.com:/public_html/repositories/git-test/". Then i created new user "git" and also added authorized public key for it in the .ssh file so that it can access the remote repo. 

Now when i try to perform to clone the remote repo in the local folder i get the error ""git no address associated with name".
I think i am close to the solution but don't know what is the issue here.

Comment: That might be a name resolution problem. Make sure that whatever you are using for `myhost.com` actually resolves from your local computer.  Also, if you continue having problems can you update your question with the full command you are running and the actual error text. Thx

Comment: Thanks!  In my case, I was using a relative path like ../../other-repo.  Using ~/other-repo instead worked.