# How can I push my changes to a remote branch

Tags: git

I am on a master branch 'master' and I have 1 commit ahead
I want to create a new remote branch called 'new_remote' and push my commit there?

```
$ git branch
* master
$ git remote
old_remote

$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'old_remote/master' by 1 commit.
```

I want to push my commit to a new branch on remote called 'new remote'
Thank you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you are currently working on local branch *master*, and the new remote branch has not been created yet:

```
git checkout -b new_branch     // creates a local branch (as a copy of the current)

git push origin new_branch // push it to the remote server
```

Comment: How to create this 'new remote branch'?

Comment: After I create a local branch using the first command, how can I get my commit from my master branch to this new local branch?

Comment: @michael This new branch is already a copy of the current branch you were in.

Comment: Thanks. But why you use 'origin' in your command 'git push origin new_branch' I tried it. It said 'fatal 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository.

Comment: @michael Are you on currently logged on a directory that has a git repo? `git status`

Comment: Yes, i am. when I do 'git status', i get 'On branch new_branch'

Comment: @michael http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922210/unable-to-git-push-master-to-github

Comment: if i do 'git remote', i get '$ git remote
old_remote' so should I do 'git push old_remote new_branch' instead?

Comment: @michael I believe so, yes. If you type `git branch -a` should tell you what branch you are on.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to push your `master` branch into a `newbranch` on the remote repository called `origin` then you can run:

```
git push origin master:newbranch
```

Answer (score 2):

Although what you are trying is perfectly legal in git, from a general best practice standpoint (when you have many parallel lines of development) I'd suggest to create a local tracking branch and push it to your remote.

```
git branch --track local_branch remote_branch
```

Answer (score 1):

```
git push origin localBranchName:master
```

More generally,

```
git push remote local_branch_Name:remote_branch_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to push your changes, so:

```
git push old_remote master
```

should be enough for you. The first parameter for `git push` is the remote you want to update (in your case that's old_remote') and the second is the branch you want to push.

Instead of specifying branch with name, you can use `--all` like this:

```
git push old_remote --all
```