# How can I switch my git repository to a particular commit

Tags: git

In my git repository, I made 5 commits, like below in my git log:

```
commit 4f8b120cdafecc5144d7cdae472c36ec80315fdc
Author: Michael 
Date:   Fri Feb 4 15:26:38 2011 -0800

commit b688d46f55db1bc304f7f689a065331fc1715079
Author: Michael
Date:   Mon Jan 31 10:37:42 2011 -0800

commit b364f9dcec3b0d52666c4f03eb5f6efb7e1e7bda
Author: Michael
Date:   Wed Jan 26 13:33:17 2011 -0800

commit 4771e26619b9acba3f059b491c6c6d70115e696c
Author: Michael 
Date:   Wed Jan 26 11:16:51 2011 -0800

commit 6e559cb951b9bfa14243b925c1972a1bd2586d59
Author: Michael 
Date:   Fri Jan 21 11:42:27 2011 -0800
```

How can I roll back my previous 4 commits locally in a branch?
In other words, how can I create a branch without my latest 4 commits (assume I have the SHA of that commit from git log)?

Answer (score 415, accepted):

To create a new branch (locally):

- With the commit hash (or part of it)

  ```
  git checkout -b new_branch 6e559cb
  ```
- or to go back 4 commits from HEAD

  ```
  git checkout -b new_branch HEAD~4
  ```

Once your new branch is created (locally), you might want to replicate this change on a remote of the same name: [How can I push my changes to a remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697326/how-can-i-push-my-changes-to-a-remote-branch)

---

For **discarding the last three commits**, see [Lunaryorn's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4940084/759452).

---

For **moving your current branch HEAD to the specified commit without creating a new branch**, see [Arpiagar's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30988318/759452).

Answer (score 324):

All the above commands create a new branch and with the latest commit being the one specified in the command, but just in case you want your current branch `HEAD` to move to the specified commit, below is the command:

```
 git checkout <commit_hash>
```

It **detaches** and point the `HEAD` to specified commit and saves from creating a new branch when the user just wants to view the branch state till that particular commit.

---

You then might want to go back to the latest commit & fix the detached HEAD:

[Fix a Git detached head?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228760/fix-a-git-detached-head)

Comment: This would detach the head.  Not convenient.

Comment: even if the `<commit_hash>` is in different branch which is ahead ?

Comment: The linked question just says to **`git checkout master`**, alongside one or two edge cases that may apply to certain situations.

Comment: how to again apply a specific commit hash when the branch is in a detached HEAD state.

Comment: I was looking for this.

Answer (score 117):

If you want to throw the latest four commits away, use:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^^^^
```

Alternatively, you can specify the hash of a commit you want to reset to:

```
git reset --hard 6e559cb
```

Comment: This leaves out the branching step. If he runs exactly what is shown here, he will permanently lose those top commits.

Comment: Well, not necessarily permanently - one could get the SHA of the previous head via `git reflog` and reset back to it - but it would be throwing them away, yes.

Comment: If the commits are pushed first then reset, they can be retrieved again with just a pull.

Comment: I would recommend to switch to a a new branch first before running this command  because this will remove all you recent changes and move your branch to a specific commit   in the past

Comment: it will delete your all-headed commits, I think the best is to create a new branch at particular commit.

Answer (score 29):

> How can I roll back my previous 4 commits locally in a branch?

Which means, you are not creating new branch and going into detached state.
New way of doing that is:

`git switch --detach revison`

Comment: This is what I was looking for. `checkout` is an operation which has too many different capabilities.

Answer (score 22):

Just checkout the commit you wants your new branch start from and create a new branch

```
git checkout -b newbranch 6e559cb95
```

Answer (score 15):

With the new [git switch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) command, we can either:

- `git switch -c <new-branch> <commit>` to create a new branch named `<new-branch>` starting at `<commit>`
- `git switch --detach <commit>` to switch to a commit for inspection and discardable experiments. See [DETACHED HEAD](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_detached_head) for details.