# Getting files from a Git repository

Tags: windows, git, version-control

This is a rather embarrassing question, but I am rather pressed for time, and can get on with other work while someone far more knowledgeable in Git than me could answer it in seconds.

I've just done a fetch from a remote repo, but I have no working copy files.  I'm using Git GUI on Windows, and I can visualise the history, and at some point I could see the file structure of the solution, but I can't find how again.  Most operations require me to select a revision, but none are available in the dropdown, and HEAD is not a valid revision for some reason.  How do I get the actual source files I need?

Comment: You'll probably want to get familiar with the command-line interface when using `git`. Could you update your question with the output of `git branch -a`? There is most likely a remote branch you want to check out locally, like in VonC's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use a commit to:

- checkout it (which will create the working tree)
- create a local branch

See [How can I switch my git repository to a particular commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940054/how-can-i-switch-my-git-repository-to-a-particular-commit/4940090#4940090):

```
git checkout -b new_branch 6e559cb
```

That commit would be the "start point revision" mentioned by [Adrian Shum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395202/adrian-shum) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623159/getting-files-from-a-git-repository/6623285#6623285).

Comment: I actually just came right doing a clone from the remote.  Clone only appears as an option when you start Git GUI, I didn't see it anywhere inside the app.

Comment: @ProfK: that's possible since I almost only use command-line interface with git, and not "git Gui".

Answer (score 1):

Then please checkout (git checkout) to have your working copy.

You can provide the start point revision to checkout.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *start point revision* but if I try a checkout without a revision I get "you are on a branch yet to be born".