# Git switching between commits

Tags: git, version-control

I read on here and searched a lot but didn't find the answer, so Is there a way to switch between commits like you do with branches.Let's say I have these commits: `a;b;c` where `c` is my last commit, can I switch back to commit `a`? Or you have to do a `git diff` and modify the files manually?

Comment: A branch _is_ a commit (with a symbolic name, but a commit nevertheless)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I switch my git repository to a particular commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940054/how-can-i-switch-my-git-repository-to-a-particular-commit)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just type `git checkout a`.  Or perhaps more usefully, `git checkout -b mybranch a`, to checkout `a` as a new branch `mybranch`.

If you want to revert `b` and `c`, you can use `git revert`, or to remove them entirely from your current branch's history, you could `git rebase -i a` and throw them out.

Even if you were going to use `git diff`, you wouldn't have to do anything manually.  Check out `git format-patch`, `git apply`, and `git am` to automate creating and applying patches.

Comment: So I guess that it's not possibile to switch between commits, only if you create branches and than switch between them? I'm right?

Comment: Or I can do `git revert b(which stand for the commit ID)` ?

Comment: There's also `git reset --hard`.

Comment: @svick - good idea, much better than mine I think... must have slipped my mind while writing.

Comment: @Uffo - yes that's correct.  But depending on what you want to do, that may or may not be a good plan.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a branch from the revision you want to work from. The revision number can be seen using

```
   git log
```

Branch out from the previous revision

```
 git branch -f branchname rev
```

Comment: This is good just in case you have created branches, but not when you have only the master branch and you want to switch between commits I guess

Comment: You can force your master branch to point to older revision. Use the master as the branchname

Answer (score 1):

git uses the definition of a commitish. git defines a commitish as:

> commit-ish
>
> Indicates a commit or tag object name. A command that takes a commit-ish
>   argument ultimately wants to operate on a commit object but automatically 
>   dereferences tag objects that point at a commit.

This seems slightly incomplete as branches are also often treated as commit-ish.

Basically, you can checkout anything that has a sha-1 hash.