# Problems adding git remote repository

Tags: git

I'm having problems adding a remote repository to my local one. I first tried using Tower where I manged to add my local repo, but when it came to adding a remote repo it just said add the URL. It doesn't say anything about this URL. Should it include ssh:// my username etc. etc.

So I found [this article](http://qugstart.com/blog/ruby-and-rails/create-a-new-git-remote-repository-from-some-local-files-or-local-git-repository) and followed it precisly, until it came to adding a remote repository. It failed. Can anyone help?

`Kasper-Srensens-MacBook-Pro:~ Kasper$ git remote add origin ssh://kasperso@kaspersorensen.com:2227/www/mechatronicscluster/wp-content.git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Kasper-Srensens-MacBook-Pro:~ Kasper$`

Answer (score 8):

You have to be in a git repository to add a remote **for this specific repository**.
Use `cd` to change the current directory.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I tried to cd into the lcoal git, ran the same command still getting an error.

`Kasper-Srensens-MacBook-Pro:wp-content Kasper$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
Kasper-Srensens-MacBook-Pro:wp-content Kasper$ git remote add origin ssh://kasperso@kaspersorensen.com:2227/www/mechatronicscluster/wp-content.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
Kasper-Srensens-MacBook-Pro:wp-content Kasper$`

Comment: Then the remote is already added I guess. Type `cat .git/config` to see the config file for your repo and check if the remote is there.

Comment: Yeah it seems like it. but now I just have another problem, I can't push my local repository to remote. See my terminal output in my comment below.

Answer (score 3):

Note: if you had to execute that command outside of that exact git repository, you [can set the **`GIT_DIR`** environment variable](http://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg150323.html):

```
(
    GIT_DIR=/somewhere/else/.git; export GIT_DIR
    git <command>...
)
```

or simply using the **`--git-dir`** option to your command

```
    git --git-dir=/somewhere/else/.git <command>...
```

That would be for commands which don't need to be in a working tree (a checked out Git repository). `git remote add` fits this criteria.

Comment: Thanks. useful info, as you can see from my comment above, i didn't have luck even if I was in the local git repo.

Comment: @Kasper: what does '`git remote -v`' shows? It is very possible that the remote 'origin' has already been defined, but not for the address you want. You can add your address as a remote named "something else" than 'origin', and goes from there.

Comment: Thanks, i tried everything over again, but it seems like I always run into a wall `Kasper-Srensens-MacBook-Pro:wp-content Kasper$ git remote -vorigin ssh://kasperso@kaspersorensen.com:2227/www/mechatronicscluster/wp-content.git (fetch)
origin ssh://kasperso@kaspersorensen.com:2227/www/mechatronicscluster/wp-content.git (push)
Kasper-Srensens-MacBook-Pro:wp-content Kasper$ git push origin master
ssh: connect to host kaspersorensen.com port 2227: Operation timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Kasper-Srensens-MacBook-Pro:wp-content Kasper$`

Comment: @Kasper: check your ssh config with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922210/unable-to-git-push-master-to-github/922461#922461

Answer (score 0):

Using for example bitbucket you can easily create remote branch through their web service and then fetch remote repository in Tower (it will add new branch icon)