# Heroku push master ssh problem

Tags: git, ssh, heroku

I get this when I am trying to push to my Heroku app:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I tried regenerating the ssh keys and adding them to the remote, but no joy.  Any help.
Kinda stuck in a rut here!

EDIT: and now I get the same error from a different app that was working very recently. :/

Comment: Are you on Windows on Unix when you are doing your push?

Comment: restarted the computer and all working!! :/

Comment: excellent. But again, a `ssh -vvv` would display interesting debug information for the next time such an error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usually usefull to make a:

```
ssh -vvv yourlogin@heroku
```

in order to dispay all the operations taking place during the ssh communication.

Various causes can be at the origin of these,

- from a `$HOME` not correctly defined (usual on Windows where the environment variable `%HOME%` *isn't* defined at all by default)
- to an IP conflict address (see [this thread](http://forums11.itrc.hp.com/service/forums/questionanswer.do?threadId=1291605&admit=109447626%201305555553919%2028353475)) for the SSH daemon.

See also this [SO answer for more debug tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922210/unable-to-git-push-master-to-github/922461#922461).

Answer (score 2):

Heroku is having git problems - see Heroku server status:
http://status.heroku.com/

I just started getting this error now.

Comment: FYI - i kept trying, and just got a push to go through.  Keep at it!  Cheers.