# Can't clone RhoHub repository - access denied

Tags: git, rhomobile

I've added my ssh key to RhoHub, but I'm still getting an access denied error. Any thoughts?

```
$ git clone git@git.rhohub.com:remcat/First App.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/Ramy/App.git/.git/
Access denied...
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

$ git clone 'git@git.rhohub.com:remcat/First App.git'
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/Ramy/First App/.git/
usage: git upload-pack [--strict] [--timeout=nn] <dir>
Error executing 'git-upload-pack'...
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your remote repo url contains space, you might want to add quotes around it:

```
git clone "git@git.rhohub.com:remcat/First App.git"
```

Otherwise, it will look for a repo named '`App`', to be cloned in the local directory "`App.git`", which I suspect isn't what you want.

If the error persists, then you need to check for ssh issue, as described in "[Heroku push master ssh problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6018945/6309)", for instance.

Start then at least with a `ssh -vvvT git@git.rhohub.com`.

But, first, make sure the space in your url isn't the actual problem here.

Comment: ok, i tried single quotes (you can see it in the original question). I'll give this a shot with double quotes tonight and let you know. thx.

Comment: well i think you're right about the space but I ended up just creating a new app called "MyApp". Couldn't get the original to work.