# How can I resolve a permission denied error with git-remote-https?

Tags: git, github

I'm having trouble trying to clone a GitHub repository with the following command:

```
git clone https://username@github.com/MYPROJECT.git
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
fatal: cannot exec 'git-remote-https': Permission denied
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: You sure you got that URL right? None of my GitHub URLs look quite like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
 git clone https://github.com/username/MYPROJECT
```

Which should be the correct http address (instead of trying to access github through an ssh session) for a *public* repo.
It will take advantage of their [support for smart http](http://progit.org/2010/03/04/smart-http.html).

```
 git clone https://username@github.com/username/project.git
```

is for private repo (as [explained here](https://github.com/blog/642-smart-http-support)), which should work if your id is right and your public ssh key correctly updated on your GitHub account.
(Note: your original address was missing the `/username/` part)

The OP reports:

> my RSA keys were not used when authenticating, I did a **`ssh-add`** and added them.
>   After that it worked figured it out by running `ssh -vT git@github.com` in my terminal

Comment: I am using a private project, and it needs the username there too

Comment: @nivanka: ok, then check your ssh parameters and config: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922210/unable-to-git-push-master-to-github/922461#922461. And **don't forget the `/username/` part** (which you don't have in your question)

Comment: I don't understand. Trying to clone (no matter how) gives me that error. It is a public repository, so I should be able to clone it even without RSA key.

Comment: @Domi that was for managing the passphrase associated with the OP's private key, as he ended up using an ssh url. In your case, start by trying to clone your repo using https, and check the case (the url is case sensitive)

Comment: @VonC Its a 100% exact copy&paste of the URL, using https from github and I get that error. I use TerminalIDE on Android. Can I somehow increase verbosity to figure out what goes wrong there?

Comment: @Domi a `git clone --verbose` can help, as well as set `GIT_TRACE=2` before the `git clone`.

Answer (score 1):

Every GitHub project has a 'clone url' widget to help you select the URL you need. Select it's access method (GIT/HTTP/etc.) and copy the url.

If it's your own project (/ have write access to the project):

`git clone git@github.com:username/project.git`

or

`git clone https://username@github.com/username/project.git`

If you want a readonly clone:

`git clone https://github.com/username/project.git`

Comment: You last one is actually a read/write address, only for public repo. The OP needs a read/write address for a private repo (which is your second one).

Comment: I don't know about privated repos, but a https without specifying a user can only be read access. In that case the server has no knowledge about the user. (just like plain HTTP)

Comment: The problem really was my RSA keys were not used when authenticating, I did a 
ssh-add and added them after that it worked 

figured it out by running `ssh -vT git@github.com` in my terminal

thanks guys

Comment: @Grad: I use your last one everyday to push to my repo. The user is specified in my `.netrc` file. http://publicfields.blogspot.com/2011/01/https-push-to-github.html. And to be sure, I have specified the `github.user` and `github.token` config entries.

Comment: But the `.netrc` config just adds the username (and password) to the request. (And then would be equal to the second line). (But it's an inventive method indeed, never thought of it...)

Answer (score -1):

Disabling the antivirus resolved this issue for me.