# Using and setting up Git

Tags: git, github, push

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to Git-push master to Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922210/unable-to-git-push-master-to-github)

I have a Github account set up by another user who already checked in the code and create a repo. I just downloaded, installed, and added SSH keys to Git/Github. Now what do I need to do to get my code up to the master?

I have never used Git and the online tutorials are confusing to me.

Comment: Search here before post please. This can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922210/unable-to-git-push-master-to-github

Comment: That question and answer look a lot more complicated than this one. I can see why @chris wouldn't think the answer was applicable. Sometimes we need to think like a newbie.

Answer (score 2):

First, at the root of your repository do: 
`git remote add origin <url of your repo>`

Then:
`git push origin master`

If you aren't comfortable with the command-line, then there are many git GUIs to choose from to make it easier: http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis