# Cannot push ruby on rails app to Heroku - network issue?

Tags: heroku

I am in a class that is asking us to put our ruby on rails app on Heroku.  They gave us step by step instructions to set up on Heroku, which I followed.  I can login to heroku from the command line, but when I try to push my app to it, I get this:

```
Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I've pinged the server, which worked.  I've tried restarting, coming back after a day, recreating the app, which worked fine.  I checked to make sure I have Heroku tool-belt.  I've spent hours searching google.  I have yet to find a solution.

upon running `ssh -vvv mylogin@heroku` i got

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
ssh: Could not resolve hostname heroku: Name or service not known
```

upon running `ssh git@heroku.com -T` i got

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '50.19.85.154' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

so I tried `git push heroku master` again and got

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you get from a `ssh -vvv yourlogin@heroku`. That should show you all the operations taking place during the ssh communication to help debug.

Comment: Scott, I added my results to my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I got it to work!  A thanks to those who responded - they set my on my path to a solution.
So here's what I did.

I ran `ssh -vvv reneeggallison@gmail.com@heroku` which gave me

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
ssh: Could not resolve hostname heroku: Name or service not known
```

Upon researching this error, I decided to run `ssh git@heroku.com -T`, receiving this is respond:

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '50.19.85.154' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

this changed my error resulting from `git push heroku master` from

```
Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

to

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

So upon researching that error, I ran `heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` which returned:

```
Uploading SSH public key /home/renee/.ssh/id_rsa.pub... done
```

This seemed good to I ran `git push heroku master` again and met success.
So thanks everyone and good luck

Answer (score 1):

Try debugging using the following command:

```
ssh -vvv yourlogin@heroku
```

[Here are some debugging tips from an SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922210/unable-to-git-push-master-to-github/922461#922461)