# Can't access gitolite admin repo after setup

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, gitolite

I'm trying to setup gitolite on ubuntu 13.04 the following way:

I create an user for it:

```
sudo adduser \
  --system \
  --shell /bin/bash \
  --gecos 'git version control' \
  --group \
  --disabled-password \
  --home /home/git \
  git
```

I haven't got a SSH key pair, so i creat one, without passhphrase:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

then i copy it to tmp:

```
cp .ssh/id_rsa.pub /tmp/myusername.pub
```

Then change to owner of the copied key to git:

```
sudo chmod git /tmp/myusername.pub
```

then i change to the git user, and append it's bin dir to PATH:

```
sudo su git
echo "PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH" > ~/.bashrc
```

finally, run gl-setup with the copied key, and accept the default config:

```
gl-setup /tmp/local.pub
```

After it, i type exit, so i go back to the myusername user. Now i try to clone the admin repo, but it asks for password:

```
myusername@gitserver-virtualbox:~$ git clone git@localhost:gitolite-admin.git
Cloning into 'gitolite-admin'...
git@localhost's password:
```

What did i do wrong?

Comment: `gl-setup`??? That's old gitolite g2! Try gitolite g3 latest one. And for debugging ssh, try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922210/unable-to-git-push-master-to-github/922461#922461

Comment: @VonC 12.04 (LTS) comes with 1.5.4. Wheezy and 13.04 comes with 2.3. 3 ain't packaged where it counts.

Comment: @kaleissin you don't need a package: just git clone the repo ;) `git clone https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite`: you can be setup in seconds.