# Unable to clone GIT repository using SSH

Tags: git, bash, github, ssh

I have created public/private key pair using the instructions in [this link](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)  and access is given for this key from GIT. when i tried to clone the repository, i am prompted for password in GIT bash, I tried the passphrase, which i used while generating the key, it did not work and how to solve this issue.

OS: Windows 8

Answer (score 0):

One propable cause is because you haven't set the environment variable `HOME` (unless you started git with the [`git-cmd.bat`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat#L9-L10) included in the Git For Windows distrbution)

```
@if not exist "%HOME%" @set HOME=%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%
@if not exist "%HOME%" @set HOME=%USERPROFILE%
```

Ssh needs to know where to find your public/private key, and it is by default in `%HOME%\.ssh`.

As described in "[Unable to Git-push master to Github](https://stackoverflow.com/a/922461/6309)", you can debug it with a:

```
ssh -Tvvv git@server
```