# Git - unable to push into gitlab project - "unable to update URL base from redirection"

Tags: git, redirect, gitlab, git-push

I gave this remote URL for my project.

```
git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/AbdullahValley/simple-crud.git
```

**When I entered this command:**

```
$ git push -u origin master
```

**It gives some ERROR which I don't understand here.**

> fatal: unable to update URL base from redirection:
>   asked for: gitlab.com/AbdullahValley/Simple-CRUD.g/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
>   redirect: gitlab.com/users/sign_in

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to Git-push master to Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922210/unable-to-git-push-master-to-github)

Comment: redirect: gitlab.com/users/sign_in  it means you are not properly login.

Comment: Gitlab appears to be down right now (get Error 500): https://gitlab.com/

Answer (score 1):

Because it's return 500 error. https://gitlab.com/

Comment: Now server is alright.  But same problem showing.  :(

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me out of the blue, despite using https and apparently having the remotes set up correctly.

```
> git push
fatal: unable to update url base from redirection:
  asked for: https://gitlab.com/bburnskm/moveto-io.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
   redirect: https://about.gitlab.com/2018/07/19/gcp-move-update/

> git remote -v
origin  https://gitlab.com/bburnskm/moveto-io.git (fetch)
origin  https://gitlab.com/bburnskm/moveto-io.git (push)
```

Resetting the remotes with -u fixed it -

```
> git push -u origin bb-ui
Enumerating objects: 40, done.
Counting objects: 100% (40/40), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (29/29), done.
Writing objects: 100% (29/29), 3.85 KiB | 788.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 29 (delta 21), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote:
To https://gitlab.com/bburnskm/moveto-io.git
   7dce642..b67ffcc  bb-ui -> bb-ui
Branch 'bb-ui' set up to track remote branch 'bb-ui' from 'origin'.
```

Though the urls didn't change... ?

```
> git remote -v
origin  https://gitlab.com/bburnskm/moveto-io.git (fetch)
origin  https://gitlab.com/bburnskm/moveto-io.git (push)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have two factor authentication enabled within GitLab?

Comment: I have only access to push by remote URL because i did not generate SSH key for my projects.