# Visual Studio pushing to wrong URL on git push: Error encountered while pushing branch to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error

Tags: git, azure-repos

This is the URL to which I need to push:

```
https://myVault.visualstudio.com/[root]/cxmlhub
```

When I try to do a git push, I get this error:

> Error encountered while pushing branch to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
>   unable to update url base from redirection:
>
> asked for:
>
> https://myVault.visualstudio.com/[root]%2Fcxmlhub/info/refs&service=git-receive-pack
>
> redirect:
>
> https://spsprodcus1.vssps.visualstudio.com/_signin?realm=myVault.visualstudio.com&reply_to=https%3A%2F%2FmyVault.visualstudio.com [a whole long string of foobar nonesense I don't understand]
>
> Pushing to
>
> https://myVault.visualstudio.com/[root]/%2Fcxmlhub

When I first got this error, I found all these threads here on SO that deal with this error (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43835309/git-push-gives-fatal-unable-to-update-url-base-from-redirection) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43910868/fatal-unable-to-update-url-base-from-redirection) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46153332/git-unable-to-push-into-gitlab-project-unable-to-update-url-base-from-redir) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53886426/git-clone-fatal-unable-to-update-url-base-from-redirection).) In looking at those threads, I realized the solution was to change the URL to which GIT was trying to push. It was indeed wrong.

I found this thread that told me how to change the URL: [How to change the URI (URL) for a remote Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-to-change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository)

Following the steps in the anwer, I changed the `remote origin` URL to what it should be:

```
https://myVault.visualstudio.com/[root]/cxmlhub
```

When I do `git remote -v` I get back the correct URL for both `fetch` and `push`.

But now, when I try and push, I still get the same error, but with different URL's. The Error I am getting now is the one that's above.  Some notes on that error:

1) I don't know why it seems to be pushing to the correct URL but this tacked on to the end:

```
/info/refs&service=git-receive-pack
```

2) I REALLY don't understant the `redirect` part of the error message with the really bizzare URL.

3) At the end of the message, in the `Pushing to` part, it actually gets the URL correct. But, it didn't actually do the push.

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** 
Not a duplicate of [git push gives fatal: unable to update url base from redirection:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43835309/git-push-gives-fatal-unable-to-update-url-base-from-redirection). I already linked to this thread, explained that I implemented the solution and that I now get a slightly different error. I feel like the person who marked this as a duplicate didn't actually read the entire post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git push gives fatal: unable to update url base from redirection:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43835309/git-push-gives-fatal-unable-to-update-url-base-from-redirection)

Answer (score 0):

Per [@NoseKnowsAll answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56567910/109941), can you try logging into `myVault.visualstudio.com` in a separate browser before trying to git push your changes?

Comment: Yes, tried that first thing. I am able to log in, but I still get the same error.